# The audio from the WebRTC remote peer video element isn't being played

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am making an application which uses WebRTC to set up a peer to peer connection between users. When a user joins the application. They'll be put into a Socket.io room where only 2 users will be able to be in and be prompted for their audio input only. When the second user connects to the same URL. I send an event to the server to put them in the same Socket.io room as the first user and run all the WebRTC code like creating the RTCPeerConnection, RTCInceCandidates, and RTCSessionDescription instances depending on what events are being broadcasted from the server to the other connected peer, but for some reason I'm not getting the remote user's audio to play where I can hear them and they can hear me.

p2p.js file (All the code responsible for setting up the connection)

```
// roomURL.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
//     document.execCommand('copy')
// });

// roomURL.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
//     e.preventDefault();
//     if (e.clipboardData) {
//         e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', roomURL.textContent);
//     }
// });

let isInitializer = false;
let isChannelReady = false;
let isStarted = false;
let pc;
let localStream;
let remoteStream;

/**
 * - Create new RTCPeerConnection
 * - Listen for events on newly created RTCPeerConnection (onicecandidate, onaddstream, onremovestream)
 */

const pcConfig = {
    iceServers: [{
        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }]
};

const room = 'foo';

const socket = io();

if (room !== '') {
    socket.emit('create or join', room);
    console.log('Attempted to create or join room ' + room);
}

socket.on('created', function (room) {
    isInitializer = true;
    console.log('Created room ' + room);
});

socket.on('full', function (room) {
    console.log('Room ' + room + ' is full');
});

socket.on('join', function (room) {
    console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' + room);
    console.log('This peer is the initiator of room ' + room + '!');
    isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('joined', function (room) {
    console.log('joined: ' + room);
    isChannelReady = true;
});

function sendMessage(message) {
    socket.emit('message', message);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

socket.on('message', function (message) {
    if (message === 'got user media') {
        start();
        console.log('Got user media');
    } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
        if (!isInitializer && !isStarted) {
            start();
        }
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
        answer();
        console.log('Offer')
    } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
        console.log('Answer');
    } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
        const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
            sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
            candidate: message.candidate
        });
        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        console.log('Candidate');
    }
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true, video: false
}).then((stream) => {
    localStream = stream;
    console.log('My Stream', stream);
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    sendMessage('got user media');
    if (isInitializer) {
        start();
    }
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function start() {
    if (!isStarted && typeof localStream !== 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
        createPeerConnection();
        const tracks = localStream.getTracks();
        for (const track of tracks) {
            pc.addTrack(track);
        }
        isStarted = true;
        if (isInitializer) {
            call();
        }
    }
}

function createPeerConnection() {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    pc.onicecandidate = function (e) {
        if (e.candidate) {
            sendMessage({
                type: 'candidate',
                label: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: e.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: e.candidate.candidate
            });
        }
    }
    pc.ontrack = function (e) {
        console.log('Remote track added', e);
        remoteStream = e.streams[0];
        remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function call() {
    pc.createOffer(null).then((sessionDescription) => {
        pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        sendMessage(sessionDescription);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}

function answer() {
    pc.createAnswer(null).then((sessionDescription) => {
        pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        sendMessage(sessionDescription);
    });
}
```

index.js (Express server for listening for Socket.io events)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const os = require('os');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(('Server listening on port ' + port));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('create or join', (room) => {
        const clientsRoom = (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room]);
        const roomSize = (clientsRoom ? clientsRoom.length : 0);

        if (roomSize === 0) {
            console.log('Joined room with no one');
            socket.join(room);
            console.log(('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + roomSize + ' connected client(s)'));
            socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);
        } else if (roomSize === 1) {
            console.log(('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room));
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            console.log(('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + roomSize + ' connected client(s) and is full'));
            socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready');
        } else {
            console.log(('Room ' + room + ' is full'));
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
    });

    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `remoteVideo.play();` after `remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;`.

If still not works, try this:

```
try {

    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;

} catch(error) {

    remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream);
};

remoteVideo.play();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try it out in my codebase and tell you if it changes anything. Busy ATM though.